# mysql: get lines that have no equal to fields

Tags: mysql, sql

How I can get from one table the lines that have date create and date update fields no equals ?

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this properly so that, for this data

```
DateCreate    DateUpdate
NULL          NULL
NULL          2011-03-01   <<<
2011-03-01    NULL         <<<
2011-03-01    2011-03-01
2011-03-01    2011-03-02   <<<, ***
```

You want to see all the rows with `***` only, then

```
select * from tbl
where DateCreate <> DateUpdate
```

If you want all the rows with `<<<` (not equal to include null), then

```
select * from tbl
where DateCreate <> DateUpdate
  or (DateCreate is null <> DateUpdate is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    <fields>
FROM
    <table>
WHERE
    <create_field> != <update_field>
```

Comment: Re: `<>` vs. `!=`: In MySQL these are identical, cf. [Operator: Not Equal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal).

Comment: Too much redundant code. For a != b, it is a requirement that both a and b are not nulls.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi So `2011-03-01 != NULL` will be `FALSE`? As I see it the above selects the `***` from your data set if the `[...]?` block is present, `<<<` if not. (I agree, however, that your query is cleaner.)

Comment: yes - `2011-03-01 != NULL => FALSE` `2011-03-01 = NULL => FALSE` null is incomparable in both cases

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi OK, I did not know that. Will remove the redundant block.